# How can I wait a page to load with selenium htmlunitDriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit-driver

I am working on a bot for a page similar to Ad.fly. After opening the link, I want to wait five seconds for the page to load before the button to click appears.

I want to execute this with `HtmlunitDriver`. I tried with implicit wait and explicit wait, but that did not work. Somebody told me to use `FluentWait`, but I don't know how to implement it.

Here is my actual code, can someone help me understand how to implement `FluentWait`?

```
public class bot {

public static WebDriver driver;
public static void main(String[] args) {
     driver = HtmlUnitDriver();
     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     driver.get("http://bc.vc/xHdGKN");
     // HERE I HAVE TO USE FLUENT WAIT, SOMEBODY MAY EXPLAIN TO ME?
     driver.findElement(By.id("skip_btn")).click(); // element what i have to do click when the page load 5 seconds "skip ads button"
}
```

}

I would like a good method to apply... I will be grateful if you help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `FluentWait` is more suitable for a situation where the wait can range widely, let say anytime between 1 to 10 seconds. For example:

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
        .withTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

WebElement el = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
        return driver.findElement(By.id("skip_btn"));
    }
});

el.click();
```

Just to be sure, these are the import statements that you need:

```
import com.google.common.base.Function;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
```

Comment: I will try with tour conde thanks for the quick reply. If it work i will come back and assert it.

Comment: Dude i copy and paste your code and i am getting error with these line codes:

Comment: WebElement el = wait.until(new Function() {    
    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {    
        return driver.findElement(By.id("skip_btn"));    
    }
});

el.click();

Comment: Edited my answer, please try again.